# Pivot table with dynamic field names in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, pivot-table

I am creating a workbook where the user can paste in their dataset in a worksheet. This dynamic range will be used to generate a series of pivot tables on subsequent worksheets. This works well when the headers are in one language. However, I would like to know if it is possible to change the headers to another language but still automatically get the same pivot tables. This would be so that one workbook can be used for users in different languages. I realise that changing the headers changes the field names and therefore breaks the pivot tables so I imagine that it might only be possible using a VB macro to generate the pivot tables at the press of a button. My VB knowledge is limited - can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it possible without VB? Could something like [this](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/10/01/switch-languages-in-excel-workbook/) be adapted?

Comment: Do your users need to *see* the Pivot Table column names in their own language?

Comment: Preferably, yes. Are you thinking of a solution that does it in the background?

Comment: Yeah, if your users would just be interacting with the pivot table without changing its structure, the idea I had wouldn't require VBA but if you do need your users to see column headers, make changes etc then I'm not sure you can avoid VBA.

Comment: Because I don't know the pivot table you want to produce I can't walk you through it. Your best bet is to [use the macro recorder to generate VBA](http://www.howtogeek.com/162975/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-excel-macros-to-automate-tedious-tasks/) as you create a Pivot Table, then try to adapt the code accordingly. Perhaps once you've done that and run into specific problems you could come back and ask a new question.

Comment: OK, apparently it's alright for the column headers to stay in English as long as the Pivot Table field names are in the other language. So you suggest translating the field names while recording a macro, then using that?

Comment: Give it a try - as I say if you hit a wall, come back and ask a new question (with all the specific details)